# Check function call in Python in classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to write a class to control a stepped motor with a Raspberry Pi.

Example of my class:

```
class Stepmotor:
    def __init__(...):
    ...
 
    def Rotate(..):
        while (function Stop is not called):
            'motor rotate'

    def Stop(..):
        'motor stop'
```

Example of code:

```
motor = Stepmotor(..)
motor.Rotate() ---> rotate motor for 5 second
time.sleep(5)
motor.Stop() ---> stop motor
```

Here is my original code to use Raspberry Pi:

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time

class StepMot:
    gpio.setwarnings(False)
    gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
    a = []
    
    def __init__(self, in1, in2, in3, in4):
        global a
        a = [in1, in2, in3, in4]
        gpio.setup(in1, gpio.OUT)
        gpio.setup(in2, gpio.OUT)
        gpio.setup(in3, gpio.OUT)
        gpio.setup(in4, gpio.OUT)

    def gpio_controll(self, x, y, z, w):
        global a
        gpio.output(a[0], x)
        gpio.output(a[1], y)
        gpio.output(a[2], z)
        gpio.output(a[3], w)
        time.sleep(0.001)

    def RotateCW(self):
        while True:
            self.gpio_controll(0,0,0,0)
            self.gpio_controll(1,0,0,0)
            self.gpio_controll(1,1,0,0)
            self.gpio_controll(0,1,0,0)
            self.gpio_controll(0,1,1,0)
            self.gpio_controll(0,0,1,0)
            self.gpio_controll(0,0,1,1)
            self.gpio_controll(0,0,0,1)
            self.gpio_controll(1,0,0,1)

   def RotateACW(self):
        while True:
           self.gpio_controll(0,0,0,0)
           self.gpio_controll(1,0,0,1)
           self.gpio_controll(0,0,0,1)
           self.gpio_controll(0,0,1,1)
           self.gpio_controll(0,0,1,0)
           self.gpio_controll(0,1,1,0)
           self.gpio_controll(0,1,0,0)
           self.gpio_controll(1,1,0,0)
           self.gpio_controll(1,0,0,0)

   def Stop(self):
       for i in a:
           gpio.output(i, 0)
```

When I call `RotateCW` "clockwise" the motor continues to rotate even 5 seconds after `Stop` has called.

I know it's because the code is blocked in `while True` and that's because I search for a solution directly in the class. When `Stop()` is called in the code the while loop in `RotateCW()` stops.

Comment: Don't get what you mean, you never call `stop` function because `RotateCW` function never ends since you have a infinity loop inside it `while True`, and even `time.sleep(5)` doesn't run.

Comment: Yeah in fact i tried to change the while argument in the rotatecw function

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `duration` parameter to `RotateCW()` and check for it in the while loop:

```
    def RotateCW(self, duration):
        stop_time = time.time() + duration
        while time.time() < stop_time:
            ...
```

Comment: Yeah this is a possibity, but i search for a “check function call” in while argument inside the rotate function.. howevere thanks for the advice